# Which sparse Matrix representation to use with sklearn.svm.LinearSVC

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a large data set (`10 000` rows), where each row (sample) is represented by a list of bits (~`200 000` bits).Each bit represent the absence or presence of the feature in the sample. So, **it's a large (`10 000 x 200 000`) high-dimensional sparse data set**

In order to save some memory space, for each sample, I'm only saving the indices of the non zero bits.
Example for a vector with 7 features:

`[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1] ===> [2, 5, 6]`

I'm doing this for all the data set. Let the result be `X` (`10 000` variable size vectors). Exemple for an initial data set `3x4`:

```
                 [[0,0,1,0],       [[2],
  initial_data=   [0,1,1,0],  ===>  [1,2],   = X
                  [0,1,0,1]]        [1,3]]
```

Each row is labeled with either of the two labels: `malignant`or `benign`.
A linear support vector classification model (the one in `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC`) is trained on the data represented by `X`. Knowing that the aforementioned model accepts sparse input and there is seven representation possible in `SciPy`:

- csc_matrix: Compressed Sparse Column format
- csr_matrix: Compressed Sparse Row format
- bsr_matrix: Block Sparse Row format
- lil_matrix: List of Lists format
- dok_matrix: Dictionary of Keys format
- coo_matrix: COOrdinate format (aka IJV, triplet format)
- dia_matrix: DIAgonal format

Which representation is more efficient for training the model ? and how can I efficiently pass from `X` to that representation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**csr** is the way to go, which is supported by [sklearn's sources](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L206). Excerpt:

```
class LinearSVC(BaseEstimator, LinearClassifierMixin,
            _LearntSelectorMixin, SparseCoefMixin):
    ...
    ...
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr',
                     dtype=np.float64, order="C")
```

csr and many other formats are not recommended for building a sparse-matrix directly (adding stuff / changing the sparsity-structure is very costly).

Use dok_matrix / lil_matrix to build a sparse-matrix from your data (should be simple) and then convert (which is done in linear-time).

```
X = X.tocsr()
```

Also keep in mind, that all the data you pass is converted internally as liblinear, the external library used by sklearn has it's own data-structures. So if you pass the wrong format; it's a one-time conversion cost which should occur. The *pure* training-procedure does not care!

Answer (score 0):

All the formats have `to...` methods to convert to other formats.  So you can build in one format, and compute in another, without too much extra cost.

- coo_matrix - the inputs to this are easy to understand and create - just 3 arrays of the same length.
  If you already have a dense array, just give it to this format, and it will extract the indices.
- csr_matrix - this is the format that implements most calculations.  `coo.tocsr(...)` is widely used.  Notice that it can use `coo` style of inputs.  You have to know a lot more about formats to use the `indptr` style of input.
- csc_matrix - just a variant of `csr`.  Sort of its transpose.
- lil_matrix - this is also easy to understand. And is moderately good for building a matrix incrementally.
  Not as good as incremental changes to a dense array.
- bsr_matrix - really a way of building a matrix from a bunch smaller ones.  Uses `coo` format internally.  For applications which are naturally block oriented.
- dok_matrix - actually a dictionary subclass.  Ok for incremental use, but still slower than populating your own dictionary with similar keys.
- dia_matrix - lets you define the matrix in terms of its diagonals.  Just an intermediary format.  Only useful if your code has a strong diagonal aspect.